# BluetoothGattCallback - onConnectionStateChange returns status 40

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

WHat does status 40 represent?
I am trying to connect to a device in a androdi bluetooth aplication and getting status : 40?
Is this value in decimal or Hex?

if it is in Hex Bluetooth Specs says this about the error:

```
COARSE CLOCK ADJUSTMENT REJECTED BUT WILL
TRY TO ADJUST USING CLOCK DRAGGING (0x40)
The Coarse Clock Adjustment Rejected but Will Try to Adjust Using Clock
Dragging error code indicates that the master, at this time, is unable to make a
coarse adjustment to the piconet clock, using the supplied parameters. Instead
the master will attempt to move the clock using clock dragging.
```

otherwise if it is in Decimal it says this ;

```
INSTANT PASSED (0x28)
The Instant Passed error code indicates that an LMP PDU or LL PDU that
includes an instant cannot be performed because the instant when this would
have occurred has passed.
```

What is it??

Comment: Still no answer?